# Does jodd email component support templates engine?

Tags: java, email, templates, jodd

Jodd framework http://jodd.org/doc/email.html provides a lib for sending emails. Does it support some template engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not directly. Jodd email is just about sending emails. But you can very easy use any template engine (Freemarker, Velocity...) to build a message body. The flow would be like this (in pseudo-code):

```
Map context = ... // this is your context map; filled with variable values
String message = parse(template, context);   // every engine has some way to apply context to the template

Email.create()
    .from("...@jodd.org")
    .to("...@jodd.org")
    .subject("Hello!")
    .addHtml(message);
```

You can even use Jodds simple [String Template Parser](http://jodd.org/doc/stringtemplateparser.html) - very simple template parser that replaces values of the context map.